# Use youtube android player API to set video playback quality

Tags: android, api, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I'm use Youtube android player API to play videos on my android application(We are using android ICS version).
I wanted to set/control the playback quality(i.e 230p,320p,420p or 720p) using the android player API,
but on the Guide there is no such method to set playback quality. Yes such method exist in Javascript API or iFrame API but not in Android player API.

If such playback option are not available is there anyway to control HD and non-HD  via API

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere with this?

Comment: i am alsp using this api in my app. i want to set quality programetically. can you please help me if you have any idea.