# Set youtube video quality to 360p or less

Tags: android, video, youtube

I am using Youtube Api from here https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/, and I need to set the video quality to 360p or less
when video starts playing, I have checked for similar questions here which was asked 1 year ago
without no definite answer. For example:

This [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23646537/android-set-youtube-video-quality-using-youtubeandroidplayerapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17572235/use-youtube-android-player-api-to-set-video-playback-quality)

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20636057/how-to-set-to-play-only-hd-videos-in-youtube-android-player-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17572235/use-youtube-android-player-api-to-set-video-playback-quality)

[Use youtube android player API to set video playback quality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17572235/use-youtube-android-player-api-to-set-video-playback-quality)

So I dont know if someone has actually found a solution or workaround
to set playback quality as video launches and willing to share his/her knowledge.

My issue is that most times, video usually loads 720p by default on mobile regardless of whether internet connection is slow or not and I don't know why.

```
if (!wasRestored) {
            YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle style = YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.DEFAULT;
            player.setPlayerStyle(style);
            player.setFullscreen(true);
            player.setShowFullscreenButton(false);
            player.loadVideo("youtubeid");
        }
```